# Simple mediation model with latent variables becomes unidentified with observed factor

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable, identifiability, amos

I noticed that if you have a simple mediation model X -> M -> Y where all three variables are latent, AMOS doesn't complain and I can have a good fit, well-identified model.

However, when I replace X with an observed variable, the model becomes unidentified and I am required to add one constraint.

Among all the things I've tried, only one has worked, although it doesn't really make sense in practice: setting the mean of X to 0 (and for some reason by the way, setting it to a value other than 0 doesn't work).

Any ideas about what I'm missing would be greatly appreciated!